# Duplicated membership options after updated to 5.15.1

Tags: civimember

After updating to 5.15.1 I find that our membership contribution page has duplicated a couple of membership types and added "-old" to the type name. This is ridiculous confusing to the users. I don't find a way to fix this using the contributions forms, the "-old" options do not appear so I can delete, and I don't know which database table holds this information. I would just delete rows from the database to fix this so the duplicated membership types are deleted.

Edit: okay I found the civicrm_membership_type table. There are no types with a "-old" extension! What is going on? Perhaps I should delete and recreate the contribution page. What then happens to the financial ledgers? Will I destroy data? You can see the problem on this page
https://idahonativeplants.org/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fcontribute%2Ftransact&reset=1&id=7

Answer (score 0):

It might not be a membership type but just a price list - if you go to Contributions - Manage Contribution Pages and then on the far right of the table click on Configure, one of the choices is Contribution Amounts. You might see these "-old" ones listed in there. Or if it is a real membership, it might be a price set which you'd see in the same place but on the Membership Settings instead of Contribution Amounts.

Comment: It's not in those places. There are no price sets. It's like civicrm is creating the duplicated types in software. It's not in the database that I can find. I think I will just create a new membership contribution page and disable the old one and write it off to the cost of a big software update.

Comment: Okay I created a new membership contribution page, but didn't use it. I saw right away that the old page started to work correctly without the duplicated "-old" types.

Comment: Weird. Did the heat wave hit Idaho? Maybe some melted circuits...